# What's the right way to add several buttons to the left and right side at the bottom of the dialog?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, windows-forms-designer

So far, what I did to align buttons in dialog was to create a `TableLayoutPanel` and add one button to each column, then manually set column sizes sot hat the buttons fit. Where would be one empty column in the middle with flexible width.

[image]

That's certainly not the right solution. How do I do this correctly in designer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Dock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.dock?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Control_Dock).

The left buttons needs to have `Dock.Left` and the right buttons needs to have `Dock.Right`.

Please note that docking left or right means filling the container top to bottom, so you must also have a container to control the height of the buttons.

From the remarks section of the [`DockStyle` Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.dockstyle?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks) page:

> If Left, Right, Top, or Bottom is selected, the specified and opposite edges of the control are resized to the size of the containing control's corresponding edges. If Fill is selected, all four sides of the control are resized to match the containing control's edges.

Usually, you do such things with two panels, one with `Dock.Bottom`, with it's height set as the height of the buttons, and the other one with `Dock.Fill`, that will have the content.
Then, in the container docked to the bottom, you dock your buttons.

Please also note that when using `Dock`, the order which you drop the elements in the container is critical - the first button will be docked to the outer edge, and the second will be docked right after it.

From the remarks section of the same page:

> When a control is docked to an edge of its container, it is always positioned flush against that edge when the container is resized. If more than one control is docked to an edge, the controls appear side by side according to their z-order; controls higher in the z-order are positioned farther from the container's edge.

Comment: Thanks! But the theng is that the layout won't let me put more than one button in the cell.

Comment: You don't need a table layout panel, you just use regular panels.